# A reading list on experimental algorithmics

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, experimental

As in, the area of the papers in the ACM Journal on Experimental Algorithmic [JEA](http://www.jea.acm.org/).

Which were the foundational works? What are the main results? How are they characterized? Any interesting connections to other areas of computer science?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Probably the single most important guide to experimental algorithmic is David Johnson's article on how to do it, which also has lots of references.
http://www2.research.att.com/~dsj/papers/experguide.pdf

Comment: This link is dead but I think I found the paper you linked to here: http://plato.asu.edu/ftp/experguide.pdf

Answer (score 11):

Catherine McGeoch has a nice paper where she tried to popularize the field: [Experimental algorithmics](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1297797.1297818). Another similar effort is by Peter Sanders: Algorithm Engineering - An Attempt at a Definition (http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-03456-5_22).

Anyway IMO the best introduction to the field is Programming Pearl by Jon Bentley. It shows several real-world cases of application of experimental algorithmics with great connections to different areas of sience.