# Are there applications of experimental mathematics in TCS?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, application-of-theory, automated-theorem-proving, experimental

In recent years there have been major, diverse, sometimes surprising advances in *experimental mathematics* [1] for a variety of sophisticated uses such as developing/deriving exact formulas, theorem proving, resolving previously unresolved conjectures (some deep), etc., ie basically core areas of mathematical research activity.

> Are there applications of this "experimental mathematics" in TCS/complexity theory?

[1] [Experimental mathematics: examples, methods, and implications.](http://www.ams.org/notices/200505/fea-borwein.pdf) by Bailey & Borwein, Notes of the American Mathematical Society, 2005

[2] [Is "Experimental Complexity Theory" being used to solve open problems?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/524/isexperimental-complexity-theory-being-used-to-solve-open-problems), tcs.se

[3] [A reading list on experimental algorithmics](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/822/a-reading-list-on-experimental-algorithmics), tcs.se